# when to open and close connection to the database in sqlite?

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a java class that interacts with the database. In this class I have several methods to insert, select , ect

Should I do

```
SQLiteConfig  = new SQLiteConfig();
sql_C.enforceForeignKeys(true);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, s.toProperties());
```

and close de conn on every method? Or just in the beginning of the class?

Comment: You are asking multiple things here, but to your question on connection etiquette, generally speaking you want to close the connection to the database as soon as you are done with it.  In other words, _don't_ leave the connection open between calls.  This lets that connection go back to the database's pool of connections, so that other threads may use it.

Comment: Okay. I edit the question to narrow it down

Comment: For the close of the connection if you are using java 1.7 or more recent you can use the resource try , java will close the connection automatically https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html